# Multi-Domain SSL and redirections

Tags: redirects, security-certificate, multiple-domains

I have one server with the main domain being: `WebSiteA.com`. 
I've got 2 others domains on the same server: `WebSiteB.com` and `WebsiteC.com`. I want to have one website architecture with 3 different sections, with 3 differents domains.

So, when someone visits `WebsiteA.com/mycategory` I want them to see `WebSiteB.com` on this page and all the others in this category.

**So this :**

> - WebsiteA.com/mycategory/page1
> - WebsiteA.com/mycategory/page2
> - WebsiteA.com/mycategory/section/page3

**Becomes this :**

> - WebsiteB.com/page1
> - WebsiteB.com/page2
> - WebsiteB.com/section/page3

**Problem 1:** 
I first tried to change the DNS in the `WebsiteB.com` domain to point to `WebsiteA.com`. It works, but for the entire site. (I suppose I should use alias instead to limit to one section?)

**Problem 2**: I have an SSL setup on `WebsiteA.com`, but when I'm trying to reach the page with `WebsiteB.com`, I receive an error.

So I suppose I should use a Multi-Domain (UCC) SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3 different SSL certificates with 3 different domains. You can use a wild card certificate if these are sub domains. (eg. site1.example.com, site2.example.com, site3.example.com)

For WebsiteB.com in your example you could change the document root to the /mycategory/ directory. Apache used to (may still) complain about sites sharing root directories but these may not be considered the same. It still worked - just issues a warning when starting or reloading.

```
#WebsiteA.com:
DocumentRoot /var/www/websitea.com

#WebsiteB.com:
DocumentRoot /var/www/websitea.com/mycategory
```

Comment: I'm currently on this solution (3 different SSL certificate and when i try to access WebSiteB.com (Which pointed on WebSiteA.com) i've got an error. I'll try the Step on Apache to see If there's any différence. Should I use alias or point DNS Like i Did from B to A ?

Comment: You will have issues when sharing an IP address with other domains unless your hosting service supports the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension to the Transport Layer Security protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Answer (score 1):

To get a successful connection to a https website you need the proper certificate(s). Only after you got the https connection you can deal with such things as documentroot or redirects.

This means you either have to get a multi-domain certificate which contains all the sites, our you have to get different certificates for each of the sites. In the case of multiple certificates you would either need to host each of the sites on a different IP address, or you have to use SNI (server name indication), where you can host multiple https domains on the same IP. But, SNI must be supported on the browser site (the browser sends the expected hostname inside the https handshake) and while all newer browsers support it, IE8 and lower on Windows XP does not and also lots of non-browser applications support ist.

So a multi-domain certificate might be the better, but probably more expensive choice.